# garbage in loop for no reason

Tags: string, loops, garbage

i wrote a function that receives a string as a char array and converts it  to  an int:

```
int makeNumFromString(char Str[]) 
{
    int num = 0, len = 0;
    int p;
    len = strlen(Str);
    for (p = 0; p<len; p++)
    {
        num = num * 10 + (Str[p] - 48);
    }
    return num;
}
```

the problem is that no matter how long the string i input is, when "p" gets to 10 the value of "num" turns to garbage!!!
        i tried debbuging and checking the function outside of the larger code but no success.

what could be the problem and how can i fix it?
        THANKS

Comment: Your question needs a language tag. Please [edit] it and add one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `int` can only store 32 bits, so the number cannot be higher than 2,147,483,647.

Try using a type for `num` with more storage, like `long`.

Comment: thank you i successfully fixed the problem, by limiting num to be 10 digits, otherwise break; THANK YOU

Comment: A 10 digit number that is higher than the one I wrote above would still not work. Anyway, if the answer solved your issue, please mark it as solved.